# Undefined data in the DB after running a migration in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration

I generated a migration to add a new column *user_id* to the *articles* table.
The scheme.rb shows that the changes in the DB have been done.
But when I run Article.new in the console, I noticed that the structure of the new article doesn't match the structure that the scheme.rb shows. WHY??

Generating the migration:

```
rails generate migration add_user_id_to_articles user:references
```

This is the migration that Rails generates:

```
class AddUserIdToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     add_reference :articles, :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
   end
end
```

Running:

```
rake db:migrate
```

This is what the scheme.rb shows.
The new *t.integer  "user_id"* has been added to the table.

```
create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.text     "body"
t.integer  "visits_count"
t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
t.integer  "user_id"
```

And this is what the Rails console shows when I run Article.new.

```
2.2.1 :056 > Article.new
 => #<Article id: nil, title: nil, body: nil, visits_count: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

No sign of the *user_id*, when I expected *user_id nill*

Comment: have you reloaded your console after migration ?

Comment: Could you show us the controller please?

Answer (score 0):

Please type reload! on rails console and check it again with

```
Article.new
```

If it doesn't work then close rails terminal with ctrl+d and again type rails c
then check

```
Article.new
```

Comment: Ooh YEA!! Closing rails terminal with ctrl+d and type rails c and check it again did the trick. I was restarting the server but not the console. Thanks dkp and Prashant Ravi Darshan!!